# How to use regexp

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I have 'tags' table with columns (id, link). Link possible values:

```
id link
1  index
2  index/index
3  index/.*
```

when I got index, I need to select id 1. And:

```
index -> 1
index/index -> 2
index/test -> 3
```

I use something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM tags WHERE 'index/test' REGEXP link LIMIT 1
```

But it's return me id 1, if I remove LIMIT second row will be id 3. I need just full math - only id 3.

Comment: What is the link between "tags" table and tou "id/link" table ?

Comment: @Delphine "id/link" table is the tags table.

Comment: Since `'index/test'` matches both #1 and #3, how should the query choose between them?

Answer (score 0):

Also for regexp, the column identifier comes first, then the search value. When I get you right, you want to get id -> 3 whenever the search term is not index or index/index. So your regex could be something like

```
SELECT * FROM tags WHERE link REGEXP '[^index/index|^index]$'
```

Comment: >whenever the search term is not index or index/index


It's just example, I need to full math the pattern

Comment: Maybe with this RegExp : `[^index\/index|^index\/+]$`. That accepts "index/index" and "index/*" where * can be special character / letter / upper / number...